# How to run arm binary on Android platform?

Tags: cross-compiling

I want to run a "hello world" program on Android.

It is written in C, and I tried different cross-compilers.

arm-elf-gcc : when I type "./hello" on my phone with adb I get a "Segmentation Fault".
However, arm-elf-gdb runs the hello program normally, without a segmentation fault.

arm-linux-gcc : when I type "./hello" on my phone, I get "Illegal instruction"

Any ideas on how I can run my program on my phone?

Answer (score 5):

This tutorial seems to explain quite well how to build and debug native C applications for Android:
http://betelco.blogspot.com/2010/01/buildingdebugging-android-native-c.html

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you have the NDK:

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Here is the easiest way to compile a C binary for your phone:

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html

Usually $NDK(may be different) =

**Linux:**

/home/`<user>`/android-ndk

**Mac OS X:**

/Users/`<user>`/android-ndk

In Terminal:

```
# create tool-chain - one line
$NDK/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-3 --install-dir=/tmp/my-android-toolchain

# add to terminal PATH variable
export PATH=/tmp/my-android-toolchain/bin:$PATH

# make alias CC be the new gcc binary
export CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc

# compile your C code(I tried hello world)
$CC -o foo.o -c foo.c

# push binary to phone
adb push foo.o /data/local/tmp

# execute binary
adb /data/local/tmp/foo.o
```

Comment: I tried your answer, and on my desktop, It should be `CC -o foo.o -c foo.c -fPIE -pie` and `adb shell /data/local/tmp/foo.o`                
Reference: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818902/running-a-native-library-on-android-l-error-only-position-independent-executab)