# error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, controls, pie-chart

When I execute a bin file in my code, Android L 5.0 blocking the execution of these file with following error

**Error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported**

My executable files are an FFmpeg converter and a Sox converter

I moved these files from a raw folder to `/data/data/com.mypackage/app_bin` and call

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/data/data/com.mypackage/app_bin/ffmpeg {commands}")`

Could any one please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Capitalization of 'i' does not hurt you :)

Comment: Sorry i little bit speak english... i tried nothing because I have no solution now!

Comment: I hope this will help you..[http://stackoverflow.com/q/24818902/2830834]

Comment: Thanks Sagar!but i not use Android.mk compiler...i've precompilated executable!

Comment: DiD you get any help?

Comment: I am stucked on this from the last 1 month and did not get any help

Comment: https://github.com/hiteshsondhi88/ffmpeg-android