# ndk can't get executable file

Tags: android, android-ndk

Just build a simple "helloworld" using android `ndk`, but I got shard object which I supposed to get executable file. And after I pushed this file to my arm emulator, I got a segmentation fault, but real device is OK. What's the problem?
Here is my os version:

```
Darwin avator 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 i386 MacBookPro11,1 Darwin
```

Here is my `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := test-libstl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test-libstl.cpp
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

And after `ndk-build`,I got the file:

```
$file ../libs/arm64-v8a/test-libstl
../libs/arm64-v8a/test-libstl: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an error in itself - it's only the `file` utility which interprets a position independent executable (PIE) as a shared object - your executable has been built just fine.

Only Android 4.1 and newer supports PIE executables, and on 5.0, non-PIE executables aren't allowed any longer - this may be why you can't run it in the emulator. See [Running a native library on Android L. error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818902/running-a-native-library-on-android-l-error-only-position-independent-executab) for more details on this issue. If your target platform in the NDK is Android 4.1 or newer (android-16), executables will be built with PIE enabled.

Comment: this really helps me,my emulator's version is 4.0,and real device is 4.4.Just another two questions:1.Is PIE a must on android 4.1 and newer? 2.I got another file which can run on my emulator 4.0,and `file` shows: `ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped`,and i'm a little confused about this.Is this file PIE? thks.

Comment: No, PIE is not a must on android 4.1, but on 5.0 it is a requirement. The second file, which `file` says is an executable, is not PIE, and will not run on 5.0.

Comment: how can i build non-PIE executable that can run on Android 4.0?I try to set `APP_PIE := false` and `APP_PLATFORM := android-9` in `Application.mk`,but it doesnt take effect.And my ndk is r10.

Comment: It seems that setting `APP_PIE := false` doesn't have any effect - you can only use `APP_PIE := true` to enable it for the case when it isn't already enabled. But `APP_PLATFORM := android-9` in `Application.mk` should indeed work - it does work when I try it out locally. Are you sure that `Application.mk` is placed correctly (in the `jni` subdirectory)? Try adding `NDK_LOG=1` at the end of your `ndk-build` call to get more logging which may give clues to what's happening.

Comment: `Application.mk` is where it should,and add `NDK_LOG=1` give something relative like this:`Android NDK:   APP_PIE is false
Android NDK: Application local targets unknown platform 'android-9'
Android NDK: Switching to android-L`.

Comment: and i use `android list`,there's no `android-9` available target on my machine indeed.But there's `android-14` available,when i used `APP_PLATFORM := android-14` in `Application.mk`,`ndk-build` got something like above,`Android NDK: APP_PIE is false Android NDK: Application local targets unknown platform 'android-14' Android NDK: Switching to android-L`.

Comment: got it resolved.My `ndk` is r10,which only contains `android-L` platform.I've already download the latest `r10d` right now.After added `APP_PIE := false` in `Application.mk`,i got non-PIE executable file.It's interesting that `APP_PLATFORM := xxx` doesn't take effect in `r10d` now:)

Answer (score 0):

try to use **LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -static**

it help me get a **ELF 64-bit LSB executable** file.