# How to build a VNC server in android?

Tags: android, websocket, remote-server, vnc, novnc

I need to remote android phone via noVNC, so I looked for some way to do it.

First, I find the androidvncserver in [Google Code Archive](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-vnc-server/) which is the vnc server in android OS.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaWl2.png)

Fig. 1 It has a problem(only position independent executables (pie) are supported) .

---

I try the method1 to solve this problem.

Method1:
[Running a native library on Android L. error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818902/running-a-native-library-on-android-l-error-only-position-independent-executab)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SNFj.png)

Fig. 2 It seems successful.

---

Then I try to via [noVNC](http://novnc.com/noVNC/vnc.html) to remote my android phone, but now it has a big problem to remote my phone.

I don't know which step happened problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHUsB.png)

Fig. 3 noVNC

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2hsN.png)

Fig. 4 Now androidvncserver has "Bus error"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srVHA.png)

Fig. 5 The final noVNC print Screen

---

I also try the [Droidvncserver](https://github.com/oNaiPs/droidVncServer), and it failed, too.

Comment: The Android VNC server app [droidVNC-NG](https://github.com/bk138/droidVNC-NG) reached version 1.0.0 in early 2021 and we are now looking for contributors to further improve the code and add features. It is using LibVNCServer internally, which also supports Websockets. Enabling WebSockets should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a vnc server like [alpha-vnc](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.abr.android.avnc). It works on most devices and dosen't even require root.